# How to use sub Query in insert statement

Tags: c#, sql

I have tried but I get error:

> SubQuery are not allowed in this context message comes.

I have two tables `Product` and `Category` and want to use `categoryId` base on `CategoryName`.

The query is

```
Insert into Product(Product_Name,Product_Model,Price,Category_id) 
values(' P1','M1' , 100, (select CategoryID from Category where Category_Name=Laptop))
```

Please tell me a solution with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
Insert into Product
(
Product_Name,
Product_Model,
Price,Category_id
)
Select 
'P1',
'M1' , 
100, 
CategoryID 
From 
Category 
where Category_Name='Laptop'
```

Comment: `Category_Name=Laptop` should be `Category_Name='Laptop'`

Answer (score 4):

(*you didn't clearly specify **what** database you're using - this is for **SQL Server** but should apply to others as well, with some minor differences*)

The `INSERT` command comes in two flavors:

**(1)** either you have all your values available, as literals or SQL Server variables - in that case, you can use the `INSERT .. VALUES()` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
VALUES(Value1, Value2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., ValueN)
```

Note: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of column to insert data into - that way, you won't have any nasty surprises if suddenly your table has an extra column, or if your tables has an `IDENTITY` or computed column. Yes - it's a tiny bit more work - **once** - but then you have your `INSERT` statement as solid as it can be and you won't have to constantly fiddle around with it if your table changes.

**(2)** if you **don't** have all your values as literals and/or variables, but instead you want to rely on another table, multiple tables, or views, to provide the values, then you can use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
   SELECT
       SourceColumn1, SourceColumn2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., SourceColumnN
   FROM
       dbo.YourProvidingTableOrView
```

Here, you must define exactly as many items in the `SELECT` as your `INSERT` expects - and those can be columns from the table(s) (or view(s)), or those can be literals or variables. Again: explicitly provide the list of columns to insert into - see above.

You can use **one or the other** - but you **cannot** mix the two - you cannot use `VALUES(...)` and then have a `SELECT` query in the middle of your list of values - pick one of the two - stick with it.

So in your concrete case, you'll need to use:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Product(Product_Name, Product_Model, Price, Category_id) 
   SELECT 
      ' P1', 'M1', 100, CategoryID 
   FROM 
      dbo.Category 
   WHERE 
      Category_Name = 'Laptop'
```

Comment: @user3134342: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @CategoryID BIGINT  = (select top 1 CategoryID from Category where Category_Name='Laptop')
Insert into Product(Product_Name,Product_Model,Price,Category_id) 
values(' P1','M1' , 100, @CategoryID)
```